Connecting SignalR with Oracle Database(Connection with a sample table) in Dot Net Core
I'm trying to connect SignalR with my Oracle database to display real-time data from my table on my website, but I'm having trouble finding any helpful resources online. Could you provide some sample code or guidance on how I can achieve this?
I have a table containing all logged errors, and I want to display them in real-time on my website.
If you have any sample project to share it would really be helpful.

You can check these 2 blogs first, and it could support SignalR & Oracle DB Change Notification.

The sample is based on asp.net framework, you can read it first. The keypoint is we need to install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core package if we need to use asp.net core.
